# How to fix this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extraBottles'?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am having a problem with my code. It returns error log of `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extraBottles'"`

```
Internal Server Error: /employee/order/79/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/employee/views.py", line 44, in view_order
    day_.extraBottles += request.session['extraBottles']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extraBottles'
```

Comment: Share the relevant view (and if applicable models, forms, etc.).

Comment: I think the main problem is that your view is really too long and to complicated. It will be hard, if not impossible to get this bugfree. Can you share the models you use and exactly *what* you aim to do.

Comment: hi sir can you check for me im newbie in python here  the file under view. and i will  https://www.mediafire.com/file/ki53xsmo9ecnmm9/views.py/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your day_ object is None so it throws an error when you try to access the extraBottles attribute. You should check if the day object is not None before trying to access it's attribute or use getattr function.

```
if day is not None:
    day_.extraBottles += request.session['extraBottles']
```